# Creating homogeneous coordinate with w != 1 in Eigen

Tags: c++, c++14, eigen, eigen3

My goal is to convert a 3D direction vector into the homogeneous space by appending a 0 to the end of the 3-vector. I don't see a clean way to convert a vector into the homogeneous space with a w not equal to 1?

For example, something that looks like this, but with "something()" replaced would be great:

```
template <typename FT>
Ray<FT>::Ray(Eigen::Matrix<FT, 3, 1> const & origin,
             Eigen::Matrix<FT, 3, 1> const & direction)
    : _origin(origin.homogeneous())
    , _direction(direction.normalized().something()) {}
```

Looking through the docs, https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html, I don't see a simple way to do this without creating separate vectors internally, which I don't want to do.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Edit: This appears to work, but there has got to be a better way.

```
template <typename FT>
Ray<FT>::Ray(Eigen::Matrix<FT, 3, 1> const & origin,
             Eigen::Matrix<FT, 3, 1> const & direction)
    : _origin(origin.homogeneous())
    , _direction(direction.normalized().homogeneous() - Eigen::Matrix<FT, 4, 1>(0, 0, 0, 1)) {
    }
```

This works for my case, but it is not ideal in any way. If someone has a better way to just set the w component of the vector in the construction of the homogeneous vector, that would still be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the comma initializer syntax:

```
direction << direction.normalized(), 0;
```

or in the initializer list:

```
: _direction((Vector4d() << direction.normalized(), 0).finished())
```

Comment: I'm getting an error about finalized() not being defined for the comma initializer. I don't see it in the documentation either. Do you have a link to it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for typo, the proper method name is `finished`.